# magento: different format of old price for specific manufacturer

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I would like to have different format of old-price of a product if is has a specific Manufacturer (i.e. Apple).

I think I have to add something like that on **p class="old-price"** on  /template/catalog/product/price.html, but I am pretty sure it's wrong:

```
<?php $manufacturer = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');?>
<?php if ($manufacturer && in_array($manufacturer = $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'), array('Apple')) : ?>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `manufacturer` is a product attribute, and you're using one of the default Magento templates in the path you specified, you should already have the product model loaded in `$_product` and you can use the manufacturer via a magic method like so:

```
$manufacturer = $_product->getManufacturer();
```

So implementation might be something like this:

```
<?php $isOldPrice = (in_array($_product->getManufacturer(), array('Apple'))); ?>
<p<?php if ($isOldPrice) : ?> class="old-price"<?php endif; ?>>Your price here</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply, it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is:

```
<?php $manufacturer = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');?>
<?php if ($manufacturer && in_array($_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'), array('Apple'))) : ?>
```